# Exporting SQL Database To Excel missing mapping datatypes like int, smallint, etc

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I am trying to export a database I have created from Identity Framework, over to a demo production for the website I'm creating.

Secifically, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, and going to Tasks, Export Data, and using 97-03 Excel Version.  The excel file I'm targeting is a valid empty file.

When I go to edit the mappings (because the database doesn't cleanly export over automatically), it seems that it doesn't give me the option to change the data types to ones specifically like (int, smallint, etc, nvarchar)...

The data types I have available are ones like Short, Long, Varchar, etc.

I did end up getting it to show the data types I needed at one point, but then when I ran the export and it completed without errors, I ended up noticing I had the excel document opened already and none of the data actually went through...

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just take a backup and restore the database?

Comment: I am transferring the database to a live server, and not a local test development.